# IP Security (IPsec) vs Public Key Infrastructure (PKI)

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ipsec

I've found the following [question](http://www.yeahhub.com/cehv9-practice-exam-questions/chapter3-cryptography.php) on the internet and don't think the answer is right.

```
Which of the following does IPsec use?

    A) SSL
    B) AES
    C) DES
    D) PKI
```

The given answer is D, PKI which is totally different technology than IPsec.

I believe the answer should be B, as IPsec is using AES as the cryptographic algorithms.

What do you think about this? Is the given answer's right or wrong?

**Reference:**
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7321

Comment: PKI means x509 certificates and most IPsec implementations uses them (maybe there are some which uses raw public keys or openpgp, but these are rare). IPsec can use many encryption algorithms, (ipsec in windows2000 used 3des (or des?) but no aes), IPsec in newer implementations uses aes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Yeh Hub questionnaire itself isn't as educational as it could be. While it tries to simplify complex things by asking simple questions with right and wrong answers, it doesn't really explain why these answers are considered right or wrong, and leaves this reflection entirely to the user. The correct mindset while using this kind of questionnaires is trying to understand the concepts and technologies rather than memorizing the (presumably) correct answers.

[An Illustrated Guide to IPsec](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-ipsec.html) by Steve Friedl explains clearly, why this question is not so simple:

> One cause of the complexity is that IPsec provides mechanism, not
>   policy: rather than define such-and-such encryption algorithm or a
>   certain authentication function, it provides a framework that allows
>   an implementation to provide nearly anything that both ends agree
>   upon.

Therefore, there really is more than just one correct answer to this, and the answers aren't limited to the given options. On the other hand, if the question was *Which of the following does IPsec **always** use?*, non of these would have been true:

- **SSL**. While IPsec works on *internet layer*, the SSL/TLS is an *application layer* protocol. As @ecdsa mentions, IPsec may utilize SSL via IKEv2 (EAP-TLS/TTLS/PEAP), but it's not a central part of IPsec itself; IPsec establishes the mutual authentication that can utilize SSL.
- **AES** / **DES**. Just two of the many possible encryption algorithms IPsec can use.
- **PKI**. Again related to IPsec and even useful, but not entirely necessary. The secret keys could be manually configured i.e. pre-shared, too, without need for PKI.

So, either all or none are true. PKI might be *closer* just because it's involved whenever IKE is using DNSSEC for distributing keys for the encryption protocols listed in the other options. If the question was further limited using "*always*", only *authentication* would've been mutual to each and every IPsec implementation, since even encryption is optional.

Answer (score 2):

IPsec is not directly related to public key infrastructure (PKI), i.e. the use of X.509 certificates structured in certificate authorities (CAs).

The [Internet Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange) protocol (IKE), on the other hand, which is used to dynamically negotiate IPsec SAs may use PKI to authenticate the peers. But there are other authentication methods that are based on raw public keys or shared secrets.  There are even authentication methods for IKEv2 like EAP-TLS/TTLS/PEAP that rely on SSL/TLS, so that may even be a "correct" answer to the question the same way PKI is (i.e. the question is very ambiguous).

And the encryption algorithm used for IPsec SAs is a configurable parameter (usually negotiated via IKE) so there is no single one that IPsec (or rather ESP) uses, although, there are some recommended algorithms that implementations should provide. Encryption is even optional.

Answer (score -3):

This is where a security professional is too off while writing on core networking concepts ... The choice should be "Public Key cryptography" NOT "PKI" -
IPSec does use Diffie-Hellman (DH group) which is a public key cryptography (public/private key pair).

PKI - is the whole infrastructure/set of protocols typically based on X.509 certs.
All answers are wrong.